# How do I remove a file from /Library/Application Support OS 10.10.3?

Tags: macos

I used killall in Terminal to remove the app, but it didn't work. There must be other files in the folder in Application Support that didn't go away. The parent process is launchd. The app is SymantecUIAgent.app.

Answer (score 1):

Antivirus software will actively prevent you from manual removal - otherwise it wouldn't be much good as an antivirus…

Norton needs an Uninstaller app - get from https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/kb20080427024142EN_EndUserProfile_en_us